# In bash, how can I check if a file name begins with a certain string and ends with another?

Tags: bash

I have hashed values of file names that I want to run tests off of.  For example:

```
index.html
```

becomes

```
index-12345678k9.html
```

I am looking for a bash script that is something akin to the following:

```
if [ "index(-dynamically created hash).html file exists in directory" ]
then
  echo 'passed'
else
  echo 'not passed'
fi
```

Comment: Is `index.html` given as a parameter? What's the context?

Comment: If you wanted to, given `index.html`, iterate over `index-*.html`, f/e, that would be easy enough, but it's also a question distinct from the one you actually asked.

Comment: `[ "index(some sort of regex here).html" ]` doesn't really make sense; it's not comparing anything against that regex (but would, as a `test` expression, just compare whether the pattern itself is an empty or nonempty string; since that pattern is hardcoded to a nonempty string, that will only ever emit `passed`). By contrast, `[[ $foo = index?(-*).html ]]` makes sense, because it has an operand, `"$foo"`.

Comment: If what you intend to compare is *the set of files in the current directory*, that's also something we can do, but... again, not clear from the question as currently written.

Comment: thanks @CharlesDuffy.  Good call.  I am in fact looking to see if that index-hashed value.html file exists.  (I am very, very, very new to bash.)

Comment: Gotcha. I've edited my answer with an appropriate addendum.

Comment: Great!  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Checking Whether A Specific File Matches

```
shopt -s extglob   # enable "extended globbing" syntax

check_candidate() {
  local pattern=$1 candidate=$2 ext basename
  if [[ $pattern = *.* ]]; then                 # if our input file has an extension...
    ext=${pattern##*.}                          # extract that extension
    basename=${pattern%.$ext}                   # and likewise the basename
    [[ $candidate = "$basename"?(-*)".$ext" ]]  # ...checking if our candidate matches
  else
    [[ $candidate = "$basename"?(-*) ]]
  fi
}
```

...will return true, given any of:

```
check_candidate index      index-1234
check_candidate index.html index.html
check_candidate index.html index-1234.html
check_candidate index.html index-foo.html
```

but false, given any of:

```
check_candidate index.html notindex-4321.html
check_candidate index.html index-abcd.txt
```

---

#### Checking Whether Matching Files Exist

If your goal is to check whether any files exist, this would instead look like:

```
shopt -s extglob  # enable ?(...) glob syntax

check_candidate() {
  local pattern=$1
  local candidate=$2
  if [[ $pattern = *.* ]]; then
    ext=${pattern##*.}
    basename=${pattern%.$ext}
    set -- "$basename"?(-*)".$ext"   # replace argument list with files matching glob
  else
    set -- "$basename"?(-*)          # likewise, no-extension version
  fi

  [[ -e "$1" || -L "$1" ]]        # true if our argument list has at least one element
                                  # and that element is the name of a file that exists.
}
```

...where `check_candidate index.html` will return true if *either* `index.html` or any file matching `index-something.html` exists in the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```
dynamic_hash() {
    # insert hash generation logic
    echo '-12345678k9'
}

if stat -t -- index$(dynamic_hash).html >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo 'passed'
else
    echo 'not passed'
fi
```